# how to mark an area of a plot (geom_bar) which contains null data values ("NA")?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, geom-bar

I am building a function to compare two sets of time-series data (rainfall) in order to check accuracy (QC) of rain-gages that we operate.  When data files which contain gaps in record are plotted, it could cause a reviewer to believe that one or more of these gages are recording incorrectly, thus skewing the QC process.

I would like to find a way to plot a red x, a circle, or something similar on the plots to alert users that that particular station, on those particular dates, do not have data.This way users can clearly see that data is missing, and to omit that particular portion of record from the review process.

Any ideas using this df, allRN

```
         date  usgs   noaa
1  2017-01-01  0.00 0.0000
2  2017-01-02  0.57 0.0906
3  2017-01-03  0.75 0.4410
4  2017-01-04  0.00 0.5790
5  2017-01-05  0.00 0.0000
6  2017-01-06  0.01 0.0000
7  2017-01-07  0.46     NA
8  2017-01-08  0.00     NA
9  2017-01-09  0.00 0.0000
10 2017-01-10  0.00 0.0000
```

and this code:

```
  plotnames <- c(noaa = "Precip, Milton, DE, NOAA", usgs = "Precip,Ng45-02 Well, USGS")
  xdateaxis <- "3 days"  
  allRN <- allRN %>%
    gather(site, precip, -date) 

  ggplot(allRN, aes(x = date, y = precip)) + 
  labs (x = "", y = "Precipitation, inches") + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position =     "dodge", na.rm = FALSE) + 
  facet_wrap(~site, nrow = 2, labeller =     as_labeller(plotnames)) + 
  scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = xdateaxis,     date_labels = "%m-%d") + 
  theme_bw() + theme(axis.text.x =  element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

[Link to example of plot output when data is missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oc1Mh.png)

Comment: Make sure you always add some sample data so that other folks have something to work with

Comment: Sorry man!  Rookie mistake!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How's this? Using `is.na(precip)` as a value for an aesthetic, you can then make points or bars or whatever you like, as long as you set the resulting scale so that `FALSE` is `NA` and `TRUE` is your color or point shape, etc.

```
require(lubridate)
df.rain <- data_frame(date = mdy("01-01-2017") + 0:9,
                      usgs = c(0,.57,.75,0,0,.01,.46,0,0,0),
                      noaa = c(0,.0906,.4410,.5790,0,0,NA,NA, 0,0)) %>% 
  gather(site, precip, -date)

ggplot(df.rain, aes(date, precip)) + facet_grid(site~.) + 
  geom_col() +
  geom_tile(aes(x = date, y = -.1, 
                height = 0.1, width = 1, 
                fill = is.na(precip))) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(NA, "red")) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = dup_axis(breaks = -0.1, 
                                         labels = "Missing\ndata:", 
                                         name = NULL)) + 
  guides(fill = F) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]